# Scroll to the top of a scrollable pop div atomaticaly using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

First thing first, I am having a popup div, which contains a form

Here's is my div

```
<div class="addnewrule" id="add_message_0">
       <form method="post" action="" id="frmadd">
        <input type="hidden" name="filter" value="1">
        <input name="rule_id" type="hidden" value="0">
      <table class="table-responsive" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" id="" style="text-align:center; margin-top:0px;">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="left"><div id="display_msg_0"></div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="40%" align="left">Name:</td>
        <td width="60%" align="left"><input class="input_field" name="rule_name" type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="left">Type:</td>
        <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="rule_type" value="0" style="display:none;"   />
        <input type="radio" name="rule_type" value="1" checked="checked" style="display:none;"  />
        <div class="btn-group equal_btn">
            <button id="block_click" class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="setRules(0);">Block Clicks</button>
            <button id="filter_click" class="btn btn-default active" type="button" onclick="setRules(1);">Filter Clicks</button>
          </div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="left">Rule Active:</td>
        <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" id="active_0" name="active" value="1" checked="checked" style="display:none;"  />
        <input type="radio" id="inactive_0" name="active" value="0" style="display:none;" />
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" id="status_enb_0" class="btn btn-default active_btn active" onclick="setruleStatus(0,1);">Enable</button>
            <button type="button" id="status_dis_0" class="btn btn-default inactive_btn" onclick="setruleStatus(0,0);">Disable</button>
          </div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="left">Campaign ID:</td>
        <td align="left"><input class="input_field" name="camp_id" type="text" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="left" id="rRange">Filter IP Ranges:</td>
        <td align="left"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
              <td style="padding:0;" width="45%"><input class="input_field" name="start_ip" type="text" /></td>
              <td width="10%" align="center">To</td>
              <td style="padding:0;" width="45%" align="right"><input class="input_field" name="end_ip" type="text" /></td>
            </tr>
          </table></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="left" id="rUAs">Filter users agents that contains:</td>
        <td align="left"><input class="input_field" name="user_agent" type="text" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="left" id="rRefs">Filter referers that contains:</td>
        <td align="left"><input class="input_field" name="referer" type="text" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="rUrl" style="display:none;">
        <td align="left">Send Blocked Clicks to:</td>
        <td align="left"><input class="input_field" type="text" id="rule_url" name="rule_url" value="" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="left" colspan="2"><table class="copypaste" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
              <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn blue_button tab2" onclick="submitRule('frmadd',0);">Apply</a> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn orange_button tab2" onclick="cancel_popup('add_new_rule')" >Cancel</a></td>
            </tr>
          </table></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Now, here is the jquery ajax function given below.. It checks for the validation and displays the validation message in a message div...

```
function submitRule(frmId,rule_id)
{
    var data=$('#'+frmId).serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'ajax/rule_update_process.php',
        data: data,
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(jData)
        {
            if(jData.status==1)
            {
                $("#display_msg_"+rule_id).html(jData.error);
                $("#display_msg_"+rule_id).addClass('error');
                var child_div = $("#display_msg_"+rule_id);
                var parent_div = $("#add_message_"+rule_id);
                parent_div.scrollTop(parent_div.scrollTop() + child_div.position().top);
            }
            else
            {
            window.location.href='settings_rules.php';
            }
        }
      });
}
```

Since the popup is a scrollable div, i want to scroll(only within the popup div) to the top so that i can show the message div with the error message..

here'sw how i am getting the screens,.

[image]

[image]

I used this piece if code to scroll to the top of the popup div to show the error message div,

but this piece of code doesn't seem to work..

What am i doing wrong??

```
$("#display_msg_"+rule_id).html(jData.error);
$("#display_msg_"+rule_id).addClass('error');
var child_div = $("#display_msg_"+rule_id);
var parent_div = $("#add_message_"+rule_id);
parent_div.scrollTop(parent_div.scrollTop() + child_div.position().top);
```

Answer (score 0):

replace ur last line of code with this 
**parent_div.scrollTop(0,0);**

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest a very simple apprach:

```
$("#apply_button").click(function () { 
  var error_message = $("#your_error_message").css("display");

  if (error_message != "none") {
    $("#add_message_0").scrollTop(0);
  }; 
});
```

Code speaks for itself.

BR

Answer (score 0):

You can use css only brother. Example this is your form.

```
<div>
<form class="has-error">
<p>error</p>
<input name="" value="">
</form>
<div>
```

you can use the class **.has-error** to set a css codes. your css codes will only use if the error message is displayed.

```
div{ overflow-y: scroll; }
div .has-error{ height: 400px; }
```

height will defend your current section height with errors message.

Something like this on [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/anthonypagaycarbon/L9y6z3u0/)

if the message is not visible on button click, add this to your click function code

```
$( '#add_message_1' ).delay( 200 ).animate({scrollTop: 0 }, 300);}
```